# Connecting to Office Online Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

We have installed Office Online Server in standalone server and we want to connect our SP 2013 Farm environment. Current OOS Server wopizone: external-https

In CA SP Server running the following:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding  –ServerName "spwac.com.au"
```

On OOS Server

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -EditingEnabled:$true
```

However, the preview document  is not working in word, excel as well as in Power point document. Before we set EditingEnable to true, the preview is working with doc document. The edit in browser option is not available

Any settings that i missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify your WOPI zone is correct using `Get-SPWOPIZone`. If it isn't, use `Set-SPWOPIZone`.